# How to have elements automatically relocate themselves when one element changes its size in react native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I currently have a multiline `textInput` that automatically expands and a button below it. The problem is that the button's location seems to be fixed, it doesn't move down and `textInput` would just run over it.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Everything is wrapped in a `KeyboardAvoidingView`:

```
   <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding">
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>

        <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.form.prompt}</Text>

        <View style={styles.simpleContainer}>

          {this._renderForms()}

          <View style={[styles.forwardButtonLocation, styles.indentLeft]}>
            <ForwardButton
              onButtonPress={this._submitInfo}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end',}}>
          <SkipButton
            onButtonPress={this._nextState}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

`this._renderForms()` renders the corresponding form for each state, in this case, it renders:

```
<View style={styles.simpleContainer}>
        <AutoExpandingTextInput
          style={styles.textContentDark}
          placeholder={this.state.form.userInput}
          placeholderTextColor={DARK_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_SECONDARY}
          onChangeText={(userInputValue) => 
            //TODO: Saving text to nested userInput is causing problem, temporarily save it to userInputValue
            //this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, userInput: text}}
            this.setState({userInputValue}
              )}
        />
      </View>
```

Here is my style sheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  simpleContainer: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR,
  },
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: '15%',
    marginLeft: '3%',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: TITLE,
    color: DARK_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_PRIMARY,
  },
  textContentDimmed: {
    fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,
    color: DARK_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_SECONDARY,
  },
  textContentWhite: {
    fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,
    color: DARK_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_PRIMARY,
  },
  textContentDark: {
    fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,
    color: LIGHT_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_SECONDARY,
  },
  indentLeft: {
    marginLeft:'10%',
  },
  forwardButtonLocation: {
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  whiteLine: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 1,
    marginTop: 4,
    marginHorizontal: '6%',
    backgroundColor: DARK_THEME_CONTENT_COLOR_PRIMARY,
  },
});
```

Is there any way to automatically relocate the button when the size of the textInput changes?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: You havent included all your styles